# VBS Retrieve Computer OU from AD and OU Case Statement to Perform Action

Tags: vbscript, location, ou

I have this piece of code from the ScriptIT guys.

```
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
strComputer = objSysInfo.ComputerName
Set objComputer = GetObject("LDAP://" & strComputer)
arrOUs = Split(objComputer.Parent, ",")
arrMainOU = Split(arrOUs(0), "=")
wscript.echo arrMainOU(1)
```

The problem I'm having is that arrMainOU(1) echoes the OU twice. I tried setting up a simple test, but it fails. I don't see this issue covered here or on google.

```
If arrMainOU(1) = "myOU" Then
wcript.echo "true"
End If
```

I need to compare 1 value within arrMainOU(1) to an array that contains OU strings. I need a case statement that performs actions depending on whether it's OU1 or OU2 and so on.

I'm getting stuck at evaluating arrMainOU(1) though. If I output the value to a file, then it only writes one value.

Any help would be appreciated - Thank you

Comment: It echoes the OU twice as in, two message boxes, or the same value twice in one message box?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code snippet to understand  the 'SPLIT' function:

```
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
strComputer = objSysInfo.ComputerName
Set objComputer = GetObject("LDAP://" & strComputer)
arrOUs = Split(objComputer.Parent, ",")
retstring = ""
For ii = LBound( arrOUs) To UBound( arrOUs)
    arrMainOU = Split(arrOUs(ii), "=")
    For jj = LBound( arrMainOU) To UBound( arrMainOU)
        retstring = retstring & "arrOUs(" & CSTR( ii) & ") = " & arrOUs(ii) & vbTab 
        retstring = retstring & "arrMainOU(" & CSTR( jj) & ") = " & arrMainOU(jj) & vbNewLine
    Next
    retstring = retstring & vbNewLine
Next
Wscript.Echo retstring
```