# Split array and get a certain position

Tags: split, vbscript, ldap, adsi

I want to get the distinguished name of the current computer. That works:

```
Dim objSysInfo, objComp, arr, UCID 
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")

' Current computer
Set objComp = GetObject("LDAP://" & objSysInfo.ComputerName)


DN = objComp.distinguishedName
```

But I only want to save a part of the distinguished name in a new variable.

For example: The distinguished name is "OU=X, OU=Y, **OU=THAT**, DC=A, DC=B, DC=C"

I just need **"THAT"** for my variable. It is always on the fourth position beginning from the right side.

How do I do this? I started with this...

```
OU= Split (DN, ",")
```

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is nothing but a useless repetition of the tags. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to have meaning to a future site user who is skimming a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem. Your current title is useless noise. Thanks.

Comment: While there's nothing wrong with using VBScript to work with Active Directory, most AD system administrators switched to PowerShell long ago. That can make a difference in getting help for trickier AD issues and/or finding the code you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBS Retrieve Computer OU from AD and OU Case Statement to Perform Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717496/vbs-retrieve-computer-ou-from-ad-and-ou-case-statement-to-perform-action)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [documentation for Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/0764e5w5(v=vs.84)), you will see that it returns an array (zero-based index). Therefore, you need to split on `,` and get the third element (index 2), and then split that result on `=` and get the second element (index 1):

```
OU = Split(Split(DN,",")(2),"=")(1)
```